# How do I add config data to my webapi application, for every api call from middleware

Tags: c#, .net

We have an application which had been getting config info from appsettings.json file, valid throughout the application lifecycle.
Code looks something like this:
ConfigureServices under Startup.cs has

```
services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);
```

and corresponding code to load config info from appsettings.json file like this:

```
services.Configure<AppName_ConfigurationSetting>(x => configuration.GetSection("AppNameSettings").Bind(x));
```

Call just requires DI and simple call like this:

```
string constr = _configs.Value.CentralMySqlConnection;
```

But now as per new requirement,since config info will have to change for every api call ,we cant fetch from appsettings.json.
Is there a way to achieve this. Preferably something similar to what we have already been doing(via **IServiceCollection**), but from Middleware instead of Startup.cs?

Thanks in advance.